# Combine array of objects and once combined remove previous index?

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects and I need to combine the subarrays that have the same key. Here is my original array.

```
0 => 
    object(Template)[59]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=3)
          'part' => string 'hinge'
          'part_status' => string 'warehouse'
          'part_type' => string 'consumable'
1 => 
array (size=1)
  '3741852' => 
    object(Template)[61]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=4)
          'partNum' => string '3741852'
          'part' => string 'bolt'
          'part_status' => string 'shipped'
          'part_type' => string 'consumable'
2 => 
array (size=1)
  '3741852' => 
    object(Template)[61]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=4)
          'partNum' => string '3741852'
          'part' => string 'bolt'
          'part_status' => string 'shipped'
          'part_type' => string 'consumable'
```

Ultimately what I need to do, is combine both the arrays with index `3741852` and put them under the same parent index.

So I've managed to accomplish that, like this.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $data) {
    $partDetails[][$data['partNum']] = $details;
    if ($key === $data['partNum']) {
         $partDetails[$key] = $details;
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to remove the previous index [2]? Here's what I currently have.

```
0 => 
    object(Template)[59]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=3)
          'part' => string 'hinge'
          'part_status' => string 'warehouse'
          'customer_type' => string 'consumable'
1 => 
  array (size=1)
  '3741852' => 
    object(Template)[61]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=4)
          'partNum' => string '3741852'
          'part' => string 'bolt'
          'part_status' => string 'shipped'
          'part_type' => string 'consumable'
  '3741852' => 
    object(Template)[61]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=4)
          'partNum' => string '3741852'
          'part' => string 'bolt'
          'part_status' => string 'shipped'
          'part_type' => string 'consumable'
2 => 
array (size=1)
  '3741852' => 
    object(Template)[61]
      protected 'values' => 
        array (size=4)
          'partNum' => string '3741852'
          'part' => string 'bolt'
          'part_status' => string 'shipped'
          'part_type' => string 'consumable'
```

Comment: Allow me to doubt that in your index 1, you have an array of 2 items with the identical key `3741852`

Comment: That's exactly how `var_dump` displays it. What I do find odd is that it isn't showing as an array as the top one is. I'm not familiar with objects so something may be wrong. I also found it odd that they appear to have the same key.

Comment: Notice how it says array (size=1)?

Comment: I ended up just building a new array as I needed it instead of trying to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
unset( $array[ $index ] ); // remove index from array
$array = array_values($array); // It will reindex array again
```

Comment: Will give that a try when I can.

Comment: Looking at this answer again, makes me realize that it is no help to me. You are using a variable as the index but part of the reason for my question is because I have no way of knowing the index at the moment. I suppose I need something similar to `array_search` that will return the parent key but it has to search the child key instead of value.